# not authorized to use function: current_timestamp

Tags: sql, sqlite, web-sql

I am trying to compare date time in `WEBSQL` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and i am getting error :

```
not authorized to use function: current_timestamp
```

I retrieve datetime from server and store in websql ! And display the entries which are more or less then `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ! How to solve this error?

Comment: To get the current date with sqlite try `SELECT date('now');` [Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Which WebSQL implementation is this?

Comment: I'm getting this with Visual Studio 2015, Apache Cordova, in the Android emulator only.  The iOS worked fine.